# Generate "sane" sequence with "intelligent" steps

Tags: r, function, sequence

I need to generate a "sane" sequence so as to populate a `gcombobox()` from `gWidgets2`. The widget deals with the number of rows from a data frame, which will be subset via `head()`. So the sequence is fine to begin from `5` (not necessarily from `1`) and to span in "intelligent" steps until `nrow(DF)`.

I came up with the following implementation:

```
sane_steps <- function(x){
  if(x<50){
    res <- seq.int(5, x, 5)
  } else if(x<100){
    res <- c(seq.int(5, 49, 5), seq.int(50, x, 10))
  } else if(x<1000){
    res <- c(seq.int(5, 49, 5), seq.int(50, 99, 10), seq.int(100, x, 100))
  } else if(x<10000){
    res <- c(seq.int(5, 49, 5), seq.int(50, 99, 10), seq.int(100, 999, 100), 
             seq.int(1000, x, 1000))
  } else {
    res <- c(seq.int(5, 49, 5), seq.int(50, 99, 10), seq.int(100, 999, 100), 
             seq.int(1000, 9999, 1000), seq.int(10000, x, 10000))
  }
  if(!any(res %in% x)) res <- c(res, x)
  return(res)
}
```

So that:

```
> sane_steps(99)
 [1]  5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50 60 70 80 90 99
> sane_steps(523)
 [1]   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50  60  70  80  90 100 200 300 400 500 523
> sane_steps(4548)
 [1]    5   10   15   20   25   30   35   40   45   50   60   70   80   90  100  200
[17]  300  400  500  600  700  800  900 1000 2000 3000 4000 4548
> sane_steps(27304)
 [1]     5    10    15    20    25    30    35    40    45    50    60    70    80
[14]    90   100   200   300   400   500   600   700   800   900  1000  2000  3000
[27]  4000  5000  6000  7000  8000  9000 10000 20000 27304
```

Is there a more efficient way to define `sane_steps()`? And is there perhaps an existing R function that facilitates generating such "sane" sequences?

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with gwidgets

Comment: I absolutely agree, but I thought it would be useful to give some context. Should I remove the `gwidgets` tag?

Comment: Sure giving context is fine but I'm not sure the gwidgets tag is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pre-create the sequence manually and subset.

```
sane_steps <- (function() {
  master_seq <- unlist(lapply(seq_len(.Machine$double.digits), function(x) {
    by <- 10^x
    seq(by, 10*by, by)
  }))
  master_seq <- c(seq(5, 50, 5), master_seq[-seq_len(5)])
  function(y) c(master_seq[master_seq < y], y)
})()
```

## Example

```
> sane_steps(99)
 [1]  5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50 60 70 80 90 99
> sane_steps(523)
 [1]   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50  60  70  80  90 100 100 200 300 400 500 523
> sane_steps(4548)
 [1]    5   10   15   20   25   30   35   40   45   50   60   70   80   90  100  100  200  300  400  500  600  700  800  900 1000 1000 2000 3000 4000
[30] 4548
> sane_steps(27304)
 [1]     5    10    15    20    25    30    35    40    45    50    60    70    80    90   100   100   200   300   400   500   600   700   800   900
[25]  1000  1000  2000  3000  4000  5000  6000  7000  8000  9000 10000 10000 20000 27304
```

Comment: Very nice implementation. Thanks! I was curious about the `(function(){..})()` syntax. Is this orthodox? (Also, there some minor issues with the code, and I'm posting the modified version in a separate answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the accepted answer, I came up with a slightly tweaked version:

```
seq_sane <- (function(){
  master_seq <- unlist(lapply(seq_len(.Machine$double.digits), function(x){
    by <- 10^x
    seq.int(by, 10*by-1, by)
  }))
  master_seq <- c(seq.int(1, 4, 1), seq.int(5, 50, 5), master_seq[-seq_len(5)])
  function(y) c(master_seq[master_seq < y], y)
})()
#lapply(c(9,10,11,49,50,51,99,100,101,999,1000,1001,9999,10000,10001,385744), seq_sane)
#lapply(c(99,523,4548,27304), seq_sane)
```

This:

- chooses a more appropriate name
- fixes a bug where the `by` elements in the output were double (e.g. 100, 1000, etc.)
- uses `seq.int` which should be faster
- it also allows for values smaller than 5 (expands the scope of the original question)